# Glitchy Animation on Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

On my main bottom layer where the player moves and elevators move I use this frame rate:

```
var requestAnimFrame =  window.requestAnimationFrame || 
                        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
                        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || 
                        window.msRequestAnimationFrame  ||  
                        window.oRequestAnimationFrame   || 
                        function(callback) {
                        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000/60);
                        };
```

When the player dies I use this frame rate for the explosion animation.

```
var requestAnimFrameExplode = function(callback) {
                        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000/15);
                        };
```

Now all this works fine, however on one of my levels I have elevators moving up and down etc that use the main bottom layer frame rate, but when the player dies the explosion frame rate players(makes things slower so you can see the animation for 1 sec) so this makes the elevators slow down for 1 sec and makes it look glitchy.

In my game Loop I have:

```
if(Death ==true)
{
requestAnimFrameExplode(Loop); //calls loop again but slower so animation explode shows
DrawSpawnAnimation(); //this draws the explode animation
}

else
{
requestAnimFrame(Loop); //when Death is false it calls at normal fast framerate for player movement etc
}
```

My question is how to stop this glitching? How can I Make the elevators and other thing sin the loop run the same time even if the animation is playing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here’s an animation illustration that uses both requestAnimationFrame and setTimeout.**

It would be more performant to use RAF to drive both animations, but both are presented here for illustration purposes.

This RAF animation loop runs your elevator and looks like this:

```
var fps1 = 60;
function runElevator() {
    setTimeout(function() {

        // request another loop
        raf1=requestAnimFrame(runElevator);

        // update the elevator properties (current Y and directon)
        elevatorY+=elevatorSpeed*elevatorDirection;
        if(elevatorY+elevatorHeight>canvasB.height || elevatorY<30){
            elevatorDirection= -elevatorDirection;
        }

        // call the function that draws the elevator frame
        drawElevator(elevatorX,elevatorY,elevatorWidth,elevatorHeight)

    }, 1000 / fps1);
}
```

The setTimeout animation loop runs your explosion and looks like this:

```
var fps2 = 30;
function runExplosion() {

    // update the explosion properties (the current radius of the explosion)
    explosionRadius+=1.5;

    // check if the explosion is done
    if(explosionRadius<explosionMaxRadius){

        // the explosion is not done, draw another explosion frame
        drawExplosion(explosionX,explosionY,explosionRadius);

        // and request another loop 
        setTimeout(runExplosion, 1000/fps2);

    }else{

        // the explosion is done,  clear the top canvas and “we’re outta here!”
        ctxT.clearRect(0,0,canvasT.width,canvasT.width);
    }

}
```

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/YzqUF/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; padding:20px;}
    #container{position:relative;}
    canvas{border:1px solid red; position:absolute; top:0; left:0}
</style>

<script>
    $(function(){

        var canvasT=document.getElementById("canvasTop");
        var ctxT=canvasT.getContext("2d");
        var canvasB=document.getElementById("canvasBottom");
        var ctxB=canvasB.getContext("2d");

        window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
          return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
          function(callback) {
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
          };
        })();


        var elevatorX=30;
        var elevatorY=30;
        var elevatorWidth=40;
        var elevatorHeight=60;
        var elevatorSpeed=2;
        var elevatorDirection=1;

        ctxT.strokeStyle="orange";
        var explosionX=100;
        var explosionY=200;
        var explosionStartingRadius=10;
        var explosionEndingRadius=25;
        var explosionRadius=explosionStartingRadius;

        var raf1;
        var raf2;

        runElevator();


        function explode(x,y,maxRadius){

            explosionX=x;
            explosionY=y;
            explosionMaxRadius=maxRadius
            explosionRadius=10;

            ctxT.clearRect(0,0,canvasB.width,canvasB.height);
            ctxT.beginPath();
            ctxT.arc(x,y,explosionRadius,0,Math.PI*2,false)
            ctxT.closePath();
            ctxT.fillStyle="yellow"
            ctxT.fill();
            ctxT.stroke();
            ctxT.fillStyle="orange";
            runExplosion();

        }

        var fps1 = 60;
        function runElevator() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                raf1=requestAnimFrame(runElevator);

                elevatorY+=elevatorSpeed*elevatorDirection;
                if(elevatorY+elevatorHeight>canvasB.height || elevatorY<30){
                    elevatorDirection= -elevatorDirection;
                }

                drawElevator(elevatorX,elevatorY,elevatorWidth,elevatorHeight)

            }, 1000 / fps1);
        }

        var fps2 = 30;
        function runExplosion() {

            explosionRadius+=1.5;

            if(explosionRadius<explosionMaxRadius){
                drawExplosion(explosionX,explosionY,explosionRadius);
                setTimeout(runExplosion, 1000/fps2);
            }else{
                ctxT.clearRect(0,0,canvasT.width,canvasT.width);
            }

        }

        function drawElevator(x,y,width,height){
            ctxB.clearRect(0,0,canvasB.width,canvasB.height);
            ctxB.beginPath();
            ctxB.moveTo(x+width/2,0);
            ctxB.lineTo(x+width/2,y);
            ctxB.rect(x,y,width,height);
            ctxB.stroke();
            ctxB.fill();
        }

        function drawExplosion(x,y,radius){
            ctxT.beginPath();
            ctxT.arc(x,y,radius,0,Math.PI*2,false);
            ctxT.closePath()
            ctxT.stroke();
        }

        $("#explode").click(function(){ explode(150,150,75); });


    }); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<button id="explode">Explode</button>
<div id="container">
<canvas id="canvasTop" width=300 height=300></canvas>
<canvas id="canvasBottom" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain why one doesnt override the other? Like if you timeed out for 1 sec wouldnt that make the other animation choppy?

Comment: Sure, glad to explain :)  The setTimeout is asynchronous meaning that when you request a setTimeout the code **inside** the timeout will be run after the specified timeout, but the code **after** the timeout gets to run immediately (no timeout).  Therefore there is no delay for any code that is after setTimeout and your elevator animation gets to keep running uninterrupted...neat, yes?

Comment: Ok but that timeout, lets say half a second, while that is running wouldnt that mean that the whole program pause's as it is timed out? hence the glitchy action with the elevators?

Comment: No pausing...all the other code (except the timeout code) **is still running** even while the timer is counting down to trigger the setTimeout code....really...that's how it works!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to control the speed of your animation by controlling the framerate.  I recommend refactoring so that framerate is independent of animation speed.

In other words, don't slow down your explosion by lowering your framerate.  You should slow it down by making the flames / debris move less between each frame.

That said, slowing the whole level down (elevators and all) when you die sounds like kind of a neat effect ;)

Comment: It does sound good, but this is too glitchy, maybe having it go backwards and then forwards again might be cool. Still though I am not experienced enough in programming to work this out by myself :(